# Nested loops and prime numbers

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested, primes

Hello I have spent many hours now trying to figure out how this example given by my tutorial works, and there is a few things I don't understand and yes i have searched the web for help, but there is not much when it is this specific example i really want to understand.

The first thing I don't understand is that 'i' and 'j' = 2 and both the for loops has i++ and j++, won't that make 'i' and 'j' equal all the time?
So in the second for loop, if 'j' has to be less than e.g.. 4/4 = 1 then it has to be less than 1? when it has been initialized to be 2.

```
int i, j;

for(i=2; i<100; i++)
{
    for(j=2; j <= (i/j); j++)
    {
    if(!(i%j))
        break; // if factor found, not prime
    if(j > (i/j))
        cout << i << " is prime\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Put braces in all your loops, please.

Comment: Add "cout << i << j;" inside the for(j) loop to see how i & j change.

Answer (score 4):

> both the for loops has i++ and j++, won't that make 'i' and 'j' equal all the time?

Nope! `i++` increments the *outer* loop, and `j++` increments the *inner* loop. For each round of the outer loop, the inner loop can be iterated (and thus incremented) several times. So for every round of the outer loop, `j` goes through values from `2` to `i/j` in the inner loop.

I recommend you to try this code out in a debugger, or simulate it on pen and paper to understand what's happening.

Comment: So j becomes greater than i?

Comment: @Jacob, no, it doesn't go beyond the point where it's equal to `i/j`.

Comment: well i'm confused now i don't know when i and j is incremented and by how much.

Comment: @Jacob, at the end of every iteration ("round") of their respective loops, and by one each time.

Comment: so round 1, 'j' and 'i' will both be 2? and round 2 'j' and 'i' will be 3, if they increment by one each time?

Comment: @Jacob, you can't keep a single count of round, because there are two nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop on j will execute it full range for each and every value of i. so no, they will not always be equal.

And yes, when the value of i is low, the loop on j will not even get started, but then as i takes on progressively higher values, the loop on j will run a little longer for each value of i.

Just for example, think of the case `i == 81`. Then j will take on values in the range [2..9]

Comment: So j stops running when it finds a number that can be divided equally with i?

Comment: As written, the j loop will break (and thereby stop executing) as soon as i is evenly divided by j. That is probably not what you actually want to have happen.

Answer (score 0):

The code is searching for all the prime numbers between *2 and 99*, so i and j are initialized to 2.*

Understood that, the first for loop try if every number between *2 and 99* is prime, using the second for loop, which searches for divisors of i.

If the second for loop doesn't find divisors, then i is prime.

The two nested loop don't have the same value because they are nested! So when *i = 2, j=2, then j=3(and i is still 2), then j=4,(i is still 2)*........then j=99, so the second loop is ended,then also the first for loop increment : *i=3, j=2, then j=3(i is still 3)* ..... Hope i've been clear :) Ask for doubts!

Comment: But a prime number can only be divided with 1 or it self why would 'i' then be 2?

Comment: 2 is a prime number, 1 is not.

Comment: but what you are saying is 'j' will run from 2 to 99 first before 'i' will and then 'i' will run from 2 to 99? I'm really confused hehe

Comment: for every value of i(between 2 and 99), j will assume every value between 2 and i/j. So while i = 2, j = 2, then j = 3, j=4 ecc... To make your code clearer you could write *for(j=2;j<sqrt(i);j++)*, that is j goes from 2 to the square root of i.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the existing code will actually ever declare `i` to be prime, because of the upper limit on `j`. The `cout` statement that declares i to be prime triggers when `j > (i/j)`, but `j` only is incremented up to `(i/j)` (it currently will never be greater than `(i/j)`, even if `i` is prime).

Try adjusting the inner loop to be:

```
for (j = 2; j <= ceilf(float(i)/float(j)) + 1; j++)
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks @JasonMArcher, I forgot to format the code correctly